# Windows service modify logon for managed service account

Tags: windows, service, login

Windows server 2019 with a service running with a local admin account.  I have configured that application to logon with a gMSA service account.

After running with certain issues, I wished to switch back and run the service as before using the local admin account.

But unfortunately the option is disabled and I could no more modify the properties of the service.

[screen shot here with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwpfu.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't switch user account of a service using GUI after you set it to **Managed Service Account**.
But you can do it using command line.

```
sc config SERVICE-NAME obj= DOMAIN\USER password= PASSWORD
```

You can find `SERVICE-NAME` in **General** tab.
Use `.` (dot) for `DOMAIN` if you are using local account

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reset it, open an elevated CMD and type

`sc managedaccount "ServiceName" false`

After that it's not grayed out anymore